# .htaccess add .html instead of slash(/) error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I switched my website to wordpress but now url link end with slash(/) instead of .html and i don't wanted to lose my google index so After banging my head around here and there , I have finally found a solution. i created .htaccess rule that will work globally for every page.

I just updated the .htaccess file in root with below code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.html [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now any URL like this: /features/cart/ will automatically forward to /features/cart.html 
Everything was working fine but now i am getting 404 error on those page which already have .html extension.
Please advice asap, because i am loosing my indexing and keyword ranking.

Here below is the actual code of .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f

# Rewrite rule for appending .html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.html [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php/$1 [L]



redirect 301 /about_us.html /about.html
redirect 301 /about/ /about.html

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Site name: `dailydealbuilder.com`

Comment: Provide example of some URLs that are generating 404?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response link is [http://dailydealbuilder.com/whitepapers.html](http://dailydealbuilder.com/whitepapers.html) and you can check all such links on the footer of the site [http://dailydealbuilder.com/](http://dailydealbuilder.com/) , which is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reordering your rules:

```
Redirect 301 /about_us.html /about.html
Redirect 301 /about/ /about.html

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
# Rewrite rule for appending .html
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.html [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Nothing works, i pasted your code, and still getting same error. :(

Comment: Is `/whitepapers/` a WP post/page?

Comment: NO, it is just a html page.

Comment: Lots of lots of Thanks to you.. It is working now. :)

Comment: I wanted to Vote Up but requires 15 reputation.. i will surely vote up as soon as i get more than 15 reputations.

Comment: Acceptance is good enough for now :) You will get much more than 15 reps

Comment: Hi @anubhava I checked you linkedin profile you have a good experience in IT, Can you please advice me about my carrier, I want to go in Android development field. Can you please suggest me from where i should start, like core java then j2mee etc etc Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You can connect with me on Linked-In for discussion over this since SO admins won't like anything other than the question discussion.

Comment: Hi @anubhava,Now i am getting new error, my feed links are not working, http://dailydealbuilder.com/feed and   http://dailydealbuilder.com/features/reports.html/feed etc you can check feed link here: http://screencast.com/t/OXnjsekR

Comment: Awesome !! Great work anubhava, Everything is working now. :)